# How should I create a new type in MPI using a dynamic field

Tags: c++, dynamic, struct, malloc, mpi

I'm trying to send a dynamic array of Points (this is my struct), but one of my fields is a dynamic array. 
How can I create a type with dynamic field?

I took out a lot of unnecessary code. I can provide more code if needed to understand more.

In general, I have the Master computer who sends tasks to all the slaves. each slave gets a lot of values (which I took out because it is not really important) included how many points do I have, what are the dimensions of each point and the Points. 
when the slaves receive the Points they have a computation and than they send the information back to the master (I took it out as well).

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
Point* points = nullptr;
    int N,K;

int myid,numprocs;
MPI_Status status;

//Initial of MPI
MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);
MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &numprocs);
//id 0 -> Master
//else  -> Slae
MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &myid);

MPI_Datatype PointMPIType;
MPI_Datatype type[3] = { MPI_INT, MPI_INT, MPI_INT };
int blocklen[3] = { 1, 1, 1 };
MPI_Aint disp[3];

disp[0] = (char *)&points[0].size - (char *)&points[0];
disp[1] = (char *)&points[0].cordinate - (char *)&points[0];
disp[2] = (char *)&points[0].label - (char *)&points[0];

MPI_Type_create_struct(3, blocklen, disp, type, &PointMPIType);
MPI_Type_commit(&PointMPIType);


//Master send tasks
if (myid == 0)
{
    //loop thru all procs
    for (i = 1; i < numprocs; i++)
    {
        //Send the size of points
        MPI_Send(&N, 1, MPI_INT, i, WORK, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
        //Send the Dimention for each point
        MPI_Send(&K, 1, MPI_INT, i, WORK, MPI_COMM_WORLD);

        //Send all the points
            MPI_Send(points, N, PointMPIType, i, WORK, MPI_COMM_WORLD);


//Slaves recive and do tasks
else
{
    //recv the size of points
    MPI_Recv(&N, 1, MPI_INT, 0, MPI_ANY_TAG, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status);
    //Recv the Dimention for each point
    MPI_Recv(&K, 1, MPI_INT, 0, MPI_ANY_TAG, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status);

    points = (Point*)malloc(N * sizeof(Point));
    //Recv all the points
    MPI_Recv(points, N, PointMPIType, 0, MPI_ANY_TAG, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status);
        //DO SOMETHING WITH THE POINTS
}
}

 struct Point
 {
     int size;
     double* cordinate;
     int label;
 }; typedef struct Point Point;
```

Comment: do all your `Point` have the same number of `cordinate` ?

Comment: yes, same number of coordinates, means the dimension is same for each point

Comment: Then you might want to change your structure to have the data "inline". `struct Point { int size; int label; double cordinate[]; };`. You will obviously have to revise how you allocate such a struct.

Comment: Ok, now I got your message. The points will have the same coordinates for the same input. But, each Input can be different.
I read the parameters from a file, so In the file you can change the input.

Comment: If I get the question correctly, you are trying to send a (dynamic) array of a custom struct. In that case just use MPI_Gather(v)/MPI_Scatter(v). Also since C++ tag was added you might want to switch to std::vector instead of all the cumbersome pointer arithmetic.